# OpenCV: Faster rate when copying video with video writer

Tags: python, video, opencv

I open video file and copy it frame by frame to another file like this:

```
def copy1(in_file, out_file):
    capt = cv.CaptureFromFile(in_file)
    frames_num = int(cv.GetCaptureProperty(capt, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    fps = int(cv.GetCaptureProperty(capt, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS))
    frame_width = int(cv.GetCaptureProperty(capt, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    frame_height = int(cv.GetCaptureProperty(capt, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    vwriter = cv.CreateVideoWriter(out_file, cv.CV_FOURCC('P', 'I', 'M', '1'), fps, (frame_width, frame_height), True)
    for i in range(0, frames_num):
        frame = cv.QueryFrame(capt)
        if frame:
            cv.WriteFrame(vwriter, frame)
        else:
            pass
    print 'Processed', i, 'frames'
```

However when I playback the `out_file`, it is faster than the original one.
`in_file` is created form `ogv` by converting it to `mpeg1video` cutting off sound. The only difference that `ffprobe` shows between `in_file` and `out_file` is bitrate (approx. `6` times higher for `out_file`).
What does that mean?

Comment: I would test this with the most recent stable version which is 2.3.1.

Comment: Are you sure that fps of in_file is the same as out_file ? because, if in_file has 30fps and out_file is set to 10fps ... obviously, the speed of playing out_file is greater.